# Can I lump constant functions of n in this way?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, summation, boundary-value-problem, constants

I am trying to solve a separation of variables PDE problem using Complex Fourier Series to apply the final boundary condition.  So far, I have the solution $u = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty (A_n r^{-n} + B_n r^n)(C_n e^{-n\theta i} + D_n e^{n\theta i})$.

What I want and think I am algebraically allowed to do before applying the final boundary condition is drop half of each factor, to get something like $u = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty B_n r^n D_n e^{n\theta i}$.  The idea is that due to the two-sided summation, each of the $A_n$ terms can be lumped into a corresponding $B_n$ term, and each of the $C_n$ terms and be lumped into a corresponding $D_n$ term (and then I can obviously lump $B_n D_n$ into a single coefficient in preparation for the Fourier Series).

Is this correct?  The reason I hesitate is that if I use the same argument to arrive at, for example, $u = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty A_n r^{-n} D_n e^{n\theta i}$, the final answer should turn out different (either containing an $r^n$ or $r^{-n}$ factor).

Comment: Why don't you write out the summation from $n = -5$ to $n = 5$, say, and see what happens. Then you'll know if it works or not.

Comment: @mattos It seeeeeeems to work when FOILed out, just making sure.